# Multiple deployments using one helm chart and chart dependencies with alias

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I have 10 Deployments that are currently managed by 10 unique helm releases.
But these deployments are so similar that I wish to group them together and manage it as one helm release.

All deployments use the same helm chart, the only difference is in the environment variables passed to the deployment pod which is set in `values.yaml`.

Can I do this using [helm chart dependencies and the alias field](https://helm.sh/docs/topics/charts/#alias-field-in-dependencies)?

```
dependencies:
  - name: subchart
    repository: http://localhost:10191
    version: 0.1.0
    alias: deploy-1
  - name: subchart
    repository: http://localhost:10191
    version: 0.1.0
    alias: deploy-2
  - name: subchart
    repository: http://localhost:10191
    version: 0.1.0
    alias: deploy-3
```

I can now set values for individual deploys in one parent Chart's `values.yaml`:

```
deploy-1:
   environment:
     key: value-1

deploy-2:
   environment:
     key: value-2

deploy-3:
   environment:
     key: value-3
```

But 99% of the values that I need to set for all the deployments are the same.
How do I avoid duplicating them across the `deploy-n` keys in the parent chart's `values.yaml` file?

Comment: Are these values service-level or environment-specific settings?  Do you need to set `key` to `value-2` only in production, or do you need to set it to the same value every time you deploy `deploy-2`?  What sort of things are common between the services; what sort of things need to be overridden, and do they need to be overridden per service or per environment?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use helm `alias` for this purpose but you might need to change the deployment and service names because kubernetes cannot create same resources multiple times instead it will **reconfigure** the resources. So along with environment variables you need to update the deployment,services and other resources names.

your deployment file need to look something like this in **deployment.yaml** template

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: {{ .Values.deploy.name }}
spec:
 selector:
  matchLabels:
    app: nginx
 template:
  labels:
   app: nginx
  spec:
   containers:
     - name: nginx
       image: nginx
       env:
        - name: key1
          value: {{ .Values.environment.key }}
```

Similar **service.yaml** as well

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: {{ .Values.svc.name }}
spec....
```

The **values.yaml** might be something like this

```
deploy-1:
   deploy:
    name: dep-1
   environment:
     key: value-1
   svc:
    name: svc-1
deploy-2:
   deploy:
    name: dep-2
   environment:
     key: value-2
   svc:
    name: svc-2
```

Comment: Hi @Rakesh did you get a chance to look into the answer? is it useful?

Answer (score -1):

If you have 10 deployments that are similar, but have only a few differences in environment variables, you can group them together and manage them as one helm release using a single values.yaml file. Here's how you can achieve this:

Define a single dependency in your parent chart's Chart.yaml file that points to the helm chart for your deployments:

```
dependencies:
  - name: my-deployments
    version: 1.0.0
    repository: https://charts.example.com
```

Create a single values.yaml file in your parent chart's templates directory that defines the values for your deployments:

```
my-deployments:
  environment:
    key1: value1
    key2: value2
    key3: value3
```

In your deployment manifests, replace any environment variable values that vary between deployments with references to the values in the parent chart's values.yaml file:

```
env:
  - name: ENV_VAR_1
    value: {{ .Values.my-deployments.environment.key1 }}
  - name: ENV_VAR_2
    value: {{ .Values.my-deployments.environment.key2 }}
  - name: ENV_VAR_3
    value: {{ .Values.my-deployments.environment.key3 }}
```

This way, you only need to define the environment variable values that vary between deployments in the parent chart's values.yaml file, and Helm will automatically apply these values to all the deployments.

Note that this approach assumes that all of your deployments use the same Helm chart with the same structure for their deployment manifests. If this is not the case, you may need to adjust the approach accordingly to fit the specific needs of your deployments.